# How do I view two camera previews with CameraX?

Tags: android

I'm studying Android Studio and would like to view the previews of two USB cameras using CameraX. Currently, the code below only displays the preview for the left camera.

The device I'm testing on is running Android 9.

What I want to achieve is to detect the IDs of the cameras connected to the device via USB, read the IDs, and assign them to the left and right views using a camera selector. I want to display the preview screens for both cameras.

I've been looking at the Google documentation for CameraX, and it mentions using CameraManager.getCameraIdList() to retrieve camera IDs. However, it seems that there is no getCameraIdList() method available.

As I'm still not familiar with how to write code by consulting API documents, I would appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Thank you.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/videoLeft"
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/videoRight"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="900dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var cameraSelector1: CameraSelector? = null
    private var cameraSelector2: CameraSelector? = null

    private lateinit var videoLeft: PreviewView
    private lateinit var videoRight: PreviewView
    private var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService? = null

    @SuppressLint("IntentReset", "AuthLeak")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        videoLeft = findViewById(R.id.videoLeft)
        videoRight = findViewById(R.id.videoRight)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            try {
                val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                val preview1 = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(videoLeft.surfaceProvider)
                }
                // is working!
                cameraSelector1 = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

                val preview2 = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(videoRight.surfaceProvider)
                }
                cameraSelector2 = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector1!!, preview1)

                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector2!!, preview2)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                // error
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
```

Comment: Need code formatting